# Pymysql - Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 1

Tags: c#, python, xamarin, flask

I'm making a mobile app that communicates with a flask api in order to do the sql queries.

I have a very weird issue, when I start the flask web API and test it in browser, everything works, in this example (this is a method that checks if a username already exists)

`http://NETWORK_IP_ADDRR/checkusr?username=someuser&token=sometoken`

it returns:

```
{
  "exists": "true"
}
```

now if I start the Xamarin mobile application, go to the register page and check if the user already exists, I write the username "someuser" in the text box and it tells me it doesn't exist, when it clearly states that it exists above.

Now I go back in the browser without restarting the api and do the same original call: `http://NETWORK_IP_ADDRR/checkusr?username=someuser&token=sometoken`

Now it returns `"exists": "false"` from the browser itself

Funny thing is, once I restart the API while the android app is still running and type the username "someuser"

`/checkusr` in flask:

```py
@app.route('/checkusr')
def CheckUsr():
    username = request.args.get("username")
    token = request.args.get("token")
    dbnameconv = "default"

    if token == clienttoken:
        try:
            ### this is where the exception happens (it happens only when the API server 
            ### is started before the app is deployed to the android emulator)
            cursor.execute("select username from user where username=%s", (username)) 
            print(cursor.mogrify("select username from user where username=%s", (username)))
            dbname = cursor.fetchone()
            dbnameconv = dbname[0]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) ### Gives error: Pymysql - Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 1
            ### numbers can vary depending on the situation

        print(f"sent: {username} - from db: {dbnameconv}")
        if username == dbnameconv:
            return jsonify(
                {"exists":"true"}
            )
        else:
            return jsonify(
                {"exists":"false"}
            )   
    else:
        return jsonify(
            {"exists":"fail"}
        )
```

this is how I query the API in C# (Xamarin)

```cs
// this is what happens on textchanged event in the register username screen of the app
bool Exists = await calls.CheckUsrAsync(UsrTB.Text, clienttoken);

// this is the CheckUsrAsync() method that is called asynchronously 
public async Task<bool> CheckUsrAsync(string Username, string Token)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{WEBAPIURL}/checkusr?username={Username}&token={Token}");

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    CheckForm form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckForm>(responseString);
    if (form.Exists == "fail")
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool Exists = Convert.ToBoolean(form.Exists);

    return Exists;
}
```

What I can't understand is why the sql query only works if the api has started after the mobile app but 
it can be queried by browser until the mobile app has connected to the API (api that was started before the app)

I'm not hosting the API on the same machine as the android emulator, flask server is running in debug mode in the local network.

Comment: there are multiple discussions of this issue in the PyMySQL github: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/422

Comment: it still doesn't point towards a solution, am I supposed to create a new connection each time in flask? why does it only occur when I start the api before the mobile app.